# Check if debian is supported in my hardware or not?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I want to check if debian is supported in my hardware. Looking to searchers i've found `lspci` command , using it on my ubuntu vs using on debian gives different result. Should i be worried if my hardware is supported

---

lspci on ubuntu

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a12 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 34ef (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Management Engine Interface (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2c Controller #4 (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b1 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX230] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

---

lspci on debian virtual box

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

What should i do now? Is my hardware supported?

Comment: Debian 10 will support your VM with almost 100% certainty and there's a high chance it will support your real HW as well. As a desktop OS Debian Stable is really **not** the best idea but it's not clear from your post how you're going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are running Ubuntu natively and Debian on a VM.

The reason two `lspci` commands differ is that your native OS, Ubuntu, sees the real hardware, where the VM, Debian, sees the visualized hardware provided by the virtualization software. These two hardware can be different because the virtualization software simulates many of your devices rather than providing direct access to real ones.

The simulated devices can have different brands and models than what is physically installed in your computer. This is the reason why virtual machines can support a more diverse range of OSs, since they can simulate most supported devices.

I suggest using a live Debian distribution for a small period of time and see if you encounter any errors.

Note: By default, Debian comes with installation of non-free software disabled. Some devices on your computer may need non-free firmware (like the wifi card), so you may need to enable repositories that provide these software. See [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) on how to do it.